# Typescript bind this to array sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, angular, typescript

I am re-implementing a working JS solution into Typescript.
I have an array of objects that have a Geolocation in latitude and longitudes.

I want to sort them by their distance to one particular location, `currentLocation`.

I would like to store `currentLocation` as a private attribute and access it within the sort function. However, when doing `this.currentLocation` , this remains undefined in `compare`. I tried `compare.bind(this)`, but no success. `this is not defined`.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I solved it in JS with global variables, but that's not elegant. `sortByDistance` is an object method.

```
 sortByDistance() {

      this.currentPosition = Leaflet.latLng(this._currentLatLng[0], this._currentLatLng[1]);

      function compare(a, b) {
        let p1 = Leaflet.latLng(a.lat, a.lng);
        let p2 = Leaflet.latLng(b.lat, b.lng);

        if (p1.distanceTo(this.currentPosition) < p2.distanceTo(this.currentPosition))
          return -1;
        else if (p1.distanceTo(this.currentPosition) > p2.distanceTo(this.currentPosition))
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }
      compare.bind(this);
      this.sorted = this.objects.sort(compare);

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compare.bind(this)` returns a new function. Try `this.objects.sort(compare.bind(this));`

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 3):

You can change

```
 function compare(a, b) {
        let p1 = Leaflet.latLng(a.lat, a.lng);
        let p2 = Leaflet.latLng(b.lat, b.lng);

        if (p1.distanceTo(this.currentPosition) < p2.distanceTo(this.currentPosition))
          return -1;
        else if (p1.distanceTo(this.currentPosition) > p2.distanceTo(this.currentPosition))
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }
```

with

```
compare = (a, b)=>{
   let p1 = Leaflet.latLng(a.lat, a.lng);
   let p2 = Leaflet.latLng(b.lat, b.lng);

   if (p1.distanceTo(this.currentPosition) < p2.distanceTo(this.currentPosition))
      return -1;
   else if (p1.distanceTo(this.currentPosition) > p2.distanceTo(this.currentPosition))
      return 1;
   return 0;
}
```

so that `this` will be in lexical scope

Comment: It should be  like `compare = (a.b)=>{};`

Answer (score 1):

`bind` works slightly differently:

```
const boundCompare = compare.bind(this);
this.sorted = this.objects.sort(boundCompare);
```

Comment: I'm curious - Why would you add the `const` and not use `let` in Typescript? A `const` function to make sure can't override?

Comment: I prefer to use `const` over `let` whenever possible -- BECAUSE I can't re-use the variable.  When I look at something defined with `const`, I know that variable won't be re-used for any other purpose -- or change value -- for the run of the function.  It's a basic part of `functional programming`  http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html